# Какой лучше выставить glOrtho для 3d?

Tags: c++, c, opengl

Для 2d я выставлял glOrtho так, чтобы начало координат было от левого нижнего угла и размером в размер экрана. А в 3d я помню как то читал старую книгу и там был вариант что надо делить ширину на высоты `aspect = width / height`. И потом выставлять параметры умножая вроде бы aspect на нужные значения. Но правильно ли это, то есть мне надо рисовать объект посередине, может это действительно правильно, но хочу прочитать от вас, знатоков. И можно полностью привести если надо умножать aspect в glOrtho, а то искать в книге незнаю где. Какие опции выставить для glOrtho для 3d?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы уверены что Вам нужна ортографическая проекция?

`glOrtho` - ортографическая проекция, она подходит для 3д, но в экзотических случаях

```
glOrtho(left, right, bottom, top, near, far)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Камера в этом случае плоскость,  а видимый объем - параллелепипед,
>   объекты не меняют размер с дистанцией от камеры

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

`glFrustum` - 3D проекция

```
glFrustum(left, right, bottom, top, near, far)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> тут камера это точка,  а видимый объем - усеченная пирамида, дальние
>   объекты меншmе чем ближние

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ТС вроде бы нигде не указывал наличие желания перспектив, а только лишь сохранение aspect-а

Comment: @Kromster я по-этому и спросил сначала уверен ли он..

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я спутал наверное, значит glOrtho только для 2d, а как насчет glPerspective она аналог glFrustum?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ окей, просто с точки зрения базы знаний, которой пользуются другие люди, важнее  наличие хороших пар "вопрос -> релевантный ответ", чем личные консультации.

Comment: @xverizex http://nehe.gamedev.net/article/replacement_for_gluperspective/21002/

Comment: @xverizex Нет, `glOrtho` и для 3d подходит, если перспектива не нужна.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat все верно, поэтому мой ответ начинается с вопроса, это экзотический случай:)